# Angularjs vs-repeat: scroll to item

Tags: angularjs

Using [angular-vs-repeat](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat), is it possible to scroll to a specific item either by index, by selector or using Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you know desired position in pixels, then

`$timer(() => {
     containerElement.animate({ scrollTop: pos }, 0); 
})`

will do the trick. Make sure that there is no latch option set to true in vs-options.